# Go to end of `===` but not include `$`

Tags: vim, macros

Consider the following example lines:

```
$some ==thing();
$some == thing();

$some ==$thing;
$some == $thing;
```

I am writing a macro to improve these lines. With the cursor on the space after `$some`, I would like to add a space after the last = sign if there is not a space there already. The `e` command brings the cursor to the end of both the `=` and `$` characters. That is, for the strings `=`, `==`, and `===` then `e` brings the cursor to the last `=` character. However, for the strings `=$thing`, `==$thing`, and `===$thing` then `e` brings the cursor to the `$` character. Thus, I cannot rely on either `i` or `a` to properly insert a space after the `=` characters.

**How can I move the cursor to the last relevant `=` character reliably?** Note that there may be other `=` characters later on the line.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you bother yourself with creating a macro when you could simply use sed like so: `%s/=\ //g` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `e` motion command, you could search for the end of a string of `=` characters:

```
/=\+/e
```

(If you prefer to escape the literal `=` instead of the meta `+`, then you can use `/\v\=+/e`.)

Comment: Thank you! I did not realise that one could have the cursor land on the end of a searched string, in fact I have searched for this feature in the past.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're describing is because both `=` and `$` are not configured as *keyword characters*, so the `e` motion moves over instances of both. To get the effect you want, change the keyword definition (temporarily?) via

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=$
```

Note that I would rather solve this not with explicit movements and a macro, but rather with a `:substitute` command, as you can better express the places of the desired modifications with regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the keyword definition. I'm looking for solutions that I could build upon and expand, the `substitute` command doesn't seem to support all that I would like to do.